# Ошибка при запуске бота (Дискорд)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Код бота

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN="some-token"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.command(pass_context=True)  
async def test(ctx, arg):  
    await ctx.send(arg)  

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

При запуске ошибка: `BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'`

Answer (score 1):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN="some-token"
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True #если нужны события, связанные с участниками
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@bot.command(pass_context=True)  
async def test(ctx, arg):  
    await ctx.send(arg)  

bot.run(TOKEN)
```